# NewbieQ: Jupyter HTML command not working when multiple code lines

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm new to Jupyter Notebook and have this simple line of code:

```
HTML('<b>Question</b>')
Q=1
```

I have found that the first line only works when nothing else comes after it. Is this normal? Do I have to have each line of code in a separate cell?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here:

1. `HTML` creates an HTML *object*, whose [rich representation](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/5.0.0/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb) is the HTML string `<b>...`. Instantiating such an object does not display it.
2. If a cell ends in an expression (the cell has a result, in a way), the result of that expression is displayed automatically.

So a cell that *ends with* `HTML(...)` will display that HTML because it is the 'result' of the cell. If you store the HTML object in a variable, you can display it at any time. IPython has a `display` function, which is like the Jupyter rich-media version of Python's builtin `print` function. To display objects at any point:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(obj)
```

in your case:

```
display(HTML('<b>Question</b>'))
```

Or you can store the HTML in a variable and display it later or repeatedly:

```
msg = HTML('<b>Question</b>')
for i in range(3):
    display(msg)
```